# Multiple functions in one fish file

Tags: fish

If I put a file called myfunc.fish in a directory called functions, and it includes a single function called myfunc, then fish will locate it if I type myfunc as a command.

What about if I want to have a bunch of short functions in one file? How do I "include" them?

Answer (score 6):

[`source` is how you include files](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#source).

Say you have a collection of functions `thing1`, `thing2`, etc. in a single file `~/mystuff/things.fish` that you want to make available. Two good approaches are:

You can use the autoloading machinery: make the files `functions/thing1.fish`, `functions/thing2.fish`, etc. each with the same contents:

```
source ~/mystuff/things.fish
```

But a simpler approach is to just put that `source` line into your `~/.config/fish/config.fish` file. Then it will be executed for each session.